# string convert in NSDate in USA iPhone Cell is not working but its working in India iPhone Cell

Tags: ios, swift, date-conversion

I have two iPhones, one is India (with sim) and second one is in the USA (without sim). Now I am trying to convert string to date but its not working USA Phone.

Here is my code. The function name is `convertUnixTimeFromString` is going crash so I am using if condition.

```
let start = getdate //"2016-01-03 06:35:53"//
print("TheDate========\(start)")
let INPUT_FORMAT:String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let str_date:NSDate = DateUnixConvertor.convertDateFromString(start, format: INPUT_FORMAT)

 public class func convertUnixTimeFromString(string:String , format:String) -> Double
    {
        let formatter:NSDateFormatter = DateUnixConvertor.setFormatterWithFormat(format)
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
            //NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
        var date = NSDate();
        if let startDate = formatter.dateFromString(string) {

            date = startDate
        }
        //let date:NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(string)!
        let unixTime:Double  = self.convertUnixTimeFromDate(date)
        return unixTime
    }

public class func convertStringFromDate(date:NSDate,format:String)->String
    {
        let unixTime:Double = DateUnixConvertor.convertUnixTimeFromDate(date)
        let dateString:String = DateUnixConvertor.convertStringFromUnixTime(unixTime, format: format)
        return dateString
    }

public class func setFormatterWithFormat(format:String)->NSDateFormatter
    {
        let formatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        return formatter
    }

public class func convertDateFromUnixTime(unixtime:Double) -> NSDate
    {
        let date:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixtime)
        return date
    }
```

I have checked both phone zones using this code

```
func ltzAbbrev() -> String { return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation ?? "" }
var getzone:String = ltzAbbrev();
print(getzone)
```

**Response of this code**
India == **IST**,
USA == **GMT +5:30**
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abbreviations value differ based on NSLocale. Try setting [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/initWithLocaleIdentifier:) to India, so that you will get the value as IST.

**Sample code:**

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN")
dafeFormatter.locale = locale
```

Comment: Please check the region  set in settings in each phone